# Why is cudart32_50_35.dll not found?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to start learning some basic CUDA and I've managed to get the application to compile, but when I debug it, it say's:

`The program can't start because cudart32_50_35.dll is missing from your computer.`

Every possible path to the file is located in the System Environment Variables, but it still manages to fail to locate it.

I'm using Windows 8 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express to code.

Any ideas?

Comment: so do you have it for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make sure you have this in the path and **make sure you restart visual studio when you make a change to the system path**... it will still use the old path until you restart the program!

For Windows 7 the binary path for CUDA v5.0 is `%CUDA_BIN_PATH%`, or `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin`. See if it is the same for you.

Alternately, as sgar91 points out, you can just copy all the .dll files in the above path to the same place you have the exe... but this is probably a bit much. In general, you should not have to run as administrator, and I have several programs running CUDA as a standard user.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself. Be sue to always run application as administrators!

Comment: That is not the issue. Make sure `copy "$(CudaToolkitBinDir)\cudart*.dll" "$(OutDir)"` is added to the Post-Build Event of the project properties.